# Azure Front Door with Serverless web Application

Tags: azure, web-applications, architecture, azure-functions, azure-front-door

I am trying to build architecture for an application. Below are the requirements -

1. It’s an internal web application
2. Maximum number of users is 300
3. Will be used from different geographical locations
   There are few others which are not relevant to this question.

I am thinking to go for azure function for serverless approach. It was suggested in couple of articles to use Azure front door.

`Azure front door` functionality is not clear on those articles. Please help me to understand what is `Azure Front Door` and whether it is useful in above business scenario.

Comment: When you said, it will used form different locations: will the app be deployed in multiple region or just users connecting to the app are form different regions or both ?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Front Door (AFD) is an place to host and operate you external (internet-facing) API's.  AFD is the kind of thing you can use to expose internal services to the outside world in a relatively safe way.

So, if your users connect to your website over a private network (like a WAN or VPN) then you wouldn't need AFD for that.

Let's say for example that you have "private" services / data sitting in Azure, and you wanted to expose them to 3rd parties, or, to the web-app mentioned in your question which you wanted to host somewhere else, so it needs to connect to your services over the internet.  In such a case AFD would be an option to expose the internal services to the website.

If you've never exposed API's on the internet before then AFD is probably not a bad place to start, as it offers a fairly comprehensive suite of functionality (security features, observability, etc), although I have no idea how much it will cost you to run.

The [AFD website & documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/frontdoor/#overview) should provide (or link to) enough info to help you understand exactly what it offers.